# How to execute a command via command-line and wait for it to be done

Tags: c#

I'm trying to execute a command via command-line and afterwards execute another command (not in cmd) which dependes on the outcome of the former command.
The problem is that the first command takes about 2 minutes to end, and the 2nd command won't "wait" for the first one to end.
How can I hold the 2nd command to wait until the first ends?

Thanks in advance!

```
public void runCmd(){
  String command = @"/k java -jar myJava.jar";
  ProcessStartInfo cmdsi = new ProcessStartInfo("cmd.exe");
  cmdsi.Arguments = command;
  Process cmd = Process.Start(cmdsi);
}
.
.
.
runCmd();           //first command, takes 2 minutes to finish
MessageBox.Show("This Should popup only when runCmd() finishes");
```

Answer (score 50, accepted):

Use the [Process.WaitForExit](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fb4aw7b8.aspx) Method:

```
 public void runCmd()
 {
    String command = @"/k java -jar myJava.jar";
    ProcessStartInfo cmdsi = new ProcessStartInfo("cmd.exe");
    cmdsi.Arguments = command;
    Process cmd = Process.Start(cmdsi);
    cmd.WaitForExit();    
 }
.
.
.
 runCmd();        
 MessageBox.Show("This Should popup only when runCmd() finishes");
```

Answer (score 8):

You could use WaitForExit().

***Note***:

1. `WaitForExit(int milliseconds)` to wait the specified number of milliseconds for the associated process to exit.
2. `WaitForExit()` wait indefinitely for the associated process to exit.

> ```
> public void runCmd()
> {
>   String command = @"/k java -jar myJava.jar";
>   ProcessStartInfo cmdsi = new ProcessStartInfo("cmd.exe");
>   cmdsi.Arguments = command;
>   Process cmd = Process.Start(cmdsi);
>   cmd.WaitForExit(); //wait indefinitely for the associated process to exit.
> }
> .
> .
> .
> runCmd();           //first command, takes 2 minutes to finish
> MessageBox.Show("This Should popup only when runCmd() finishes");
> ```

Answer (score 7):

Even shorter:

```
Process.Start("cmd.exe", @"/k java -jar myJava.jar").WaitForExit();
```

This works because the static method `Process.Start` returns a `Process` object. Then you can call the `WaitForExit` method directly on it, without even storing it in a local variable.

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Comment: @hellow explanation added! Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`Process.WaitForExit()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fb4aw7b8.aspx) method;

> Instructs the Process component to wait indefinitely for the
>   associated process to exit.

```
// Start the process with the info you specified.
// Call WaitForExit and then the using statement will close.
using(Process cmd = Process.Start(cmdsi))
{
      cmd.WaitForExit();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the `WaitForExit();` process would be best as others have stated.

specifying a time in milliseconds for the command to exit or indefinitely as advised.