# Is there any way take backup of mongodb database using c# code?

Tags: c#, mongodb

```
    "it is showing error like :- JSON reader was expecting a value but 
    found 'mongodump'.'"

    //i tried this code but itr=s not working 
    "var cmd = new JsonCommand<BsonDocument>(" mongodump--db XEAP --out 
    F:\\");
    database.RunCommand(cmd);"
```

I want to take backup of database using c# code.

```
   "var cmd = new JsonCommand<BsonDocument>(" mongodump--db XEAP --out 
    F:\\");
    database.RunCommand(cmd);"
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Run MongoDump / MongoRestore in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16716407/run-mongodump-mongorestore-in-c-sharp)

Comment: but, there i didn't get any appropriate  solution for my question, if you have any solution please help ..

Answer (score 2):

database.RunCommand executes [MongoDB command](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/command/).

mongodump is an OS-level executable. This thread explains how to run this kind of command from C#.
[Run Command Prompt Commands](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1469764/run-command-prompt-commands)

Comment: Tanks for reply, but i don't want to create new process i just want to execute that command within current program

Comment: I don't think MongoDB would let you do that. For C# you can use WaitForExit(); https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15676058/how-to-execute-a-command-via-command-line-and-wait-for-it-to-be-done so you program waits for backup to complete, before doing anything else.